# Dimension of a vector composed of n-dimensional base vectors

Tags: python-3.x, vector, dimensions

I have an issue understanding the dimension of vectors. A vector `v` composed of `m` base vectors has a dimension `m`. However, if those `m` vectors are n-dimensional, then the dimension of `v` is `m` or `m*n`? For example, when I run the command `v.shape`, I get (28, 28, 128). Then this means that the dimension of `v` is 28x28x128? Or I just consider the base vectors, that is `28`?

Comment: You're conflating multiple definitions of dimension. The mathematical definition of the dimension of a vector space isn't necessary related to whatever a programming library calls "dimension".

Comment: Also, FWIW, the phrase _"a vector v composed of m base vectors"_ doesn't really make sense mathematical. Vector _spaces_ have basis vectors, not vectors themselves. You can say that the vector v lies in a vector space that is spanned by m basis vector, but even that isn't a particular interesting statement since we can invent vector spaces of any dimension we want that v can be a member of.